# Get root url in Keycloak login theme

Tags: keycloak, freemarker

Is it possible to get the root url in the Freemaker's template used by Keycloak login theme? The closest one I found is inside the client bean:

```
keycloak-master\services\src\main\java\org\keycloak\forms\login\freemarker\model\ClientBean.java


public String getBaseUrl() {
  return ResolveRelative.resolveRelativeUri(session, client.getRootUrl(), client.getBaseUrl());
}
```

Which can be called in a Freemaker tamplete:

```
${client.baseUrl}
```

However, the client.getRootUrl() itself is not exposed. Is it possible to get root url without changing the service source code, just using the Freemaker template in the Keycloak theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just for displaying it in the page, use Javascript and it'll be evaluated at client side:

```html
<label id="yourLabel">test</label>
<script>
  var root = window.location.origin;
  document.getElementById('yourLabel').innerHTML = root;
</script>
```

**See also:**

- [Change label text using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488714/change-label-text-using-javascript)
- [How to extract the hostname portion of a URL in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368264/how-to-extract-the-hostname-portion-of-a-url-in-javascript)